# Ctrl shortcuts not working in VLC

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, vlc

I'm experiencing some keyboard shortcuts not working in VLC after upgrading to 15.10. The problem persists in 16.04

If I just open VLC with no file loaded, almost all shortcuts involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> do nothing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> should open the "open file" dialog, but nothing happens. The exception is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> which does work to close VLC.

Oddly, if I open a file then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> starts working to close the file, but none of the other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcuts work.

Stranger still, after I've opened a file and then closed it, suddenly all the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcuts start working, but now the menus have changed color and no longer sit within the window title bar.

What could be causing this strange behaviour, and how can I fix it?

[image: VLC before opening and closing a file]

[image: VLC after opening and closing a file]

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem

Comment: Say, is this still an issue in 16.04?

Comment: @anonymous2, yes, the behaviour is the same in 16.04. The only difference I can see is that the hotkeys that don't work are now no longer listed alongside the menus until having opened and closed a file.

Comment: When logging out from a Unity session and logging in to LXDE, all shortcuts work right away. So it's very clearly a Unity related problem.

Comment: Yup, can confirm this bug on VLC 3.0.0 too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is caused by a notorious `appmenu-qt5` bug. The [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1380702) is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1380702). It sets an environment variable for qt applications and this causes many applications menu item to be problematic in Unity. VLC is one of them.

The environment variable is `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` and is set in the file `/etc/profile.d/appmenu-qt5.sh`.

#### Workaround

To workaround this bug, You can unset this variable and start VLC then. From terminal you can use this command to start VLC without this bug.

```
env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME='' vlc
```

As a permanent fix, first copy the `vlc.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applicatons/`

```
cp /usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

and then edit the line starting with `EXEC` to this line below

```
Exec=env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME='' /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U
```

Save the file. Now if you start VLC, the shortcut will work from start.

#### Update

As [reported by Jonathan Y](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742127/ctrl-shortcuts-not-working-in-vlc/823559#comment1251309_823559), it seems unsetting `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` environment variable works too! So, you can use un-setting this variable in `.desktop` file.

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY='' /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U
```

Comment: Awesome, I can confirm the `env` command works as expected. :)

Comment: @edwinksl Great! thanks for testing and verifying the result

Comment: I've also seen [a recommendation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texmaker/+bug/1386111/comments/47) to remedy this bug by unsetting `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` in a similar fashion. Can you comment on the difference between the two approaches, and which (if any) is less restrictive / should be considered 'organic'?

Comment: @JonathanY. I too has seen that recommendation. But After testing with that, I found no difference. What was your result using that one?

Comment: @JonathanY. I tested with VLC and didn't find any result. I haven't tested with Texmaker and Can't now. Can you test with VLC and let me know the result?

Comment: Yes, I have the same functionality in `vlc`, unsetting either variable. Version 2.2.2 on Xenial.

Comment: @JonathanY. Yes. Both seem to work. Thanks for the valuable input